# IntelliJ IDEA."Open existing project" vs "delete existing and reimport"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When pom.xml is selected in IntelliJ IDEA (Java+maven+git) there are two options: `Open existing project` and `Delete existing project and reimport`

What exactly is the stuff that is kept when Open Existing is selected, but reset on reimport? Is it key bindings? JDK version? File versioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimpoting a project will reset anything saved in the `.idea` folder (i.e., configurations regarding how IntelliJ interacts with your code) - inspection settings, the JDK to use (assuming it's not defined in the `pom.xml`), saved run configurations, etc.